# Cannot build phantomjs on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM

Tags: phantomjs

I have clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git and checkout branch 2.0 but I got the following error when running ./build.sh

```
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [.obj/loader/FrameLoader.o] Error 4
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/luc/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source /WebCore'
make[1]: *** [sub-Target-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/luc/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore'
make: *** [sub-Source-WebCore-WebCore-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Before running the build, I've installed all the package as described in the build documentation

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ flex bison gperf ruby perl libsqlite3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6 libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev
```

Any idea what I can be missing ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Comment: `sudo apt-get install phantomjs` they say there is no build for linux in documentation but it seems that there is.

Comment: Great, did not know about this one. Hopefully version 2.0 will be available through apt-get soon :) (it currently install 1.9.0)

Comment: Did you mean `checkout branch 2.0 but I got the following error when running `**./build.py** instead of `./build.sh`? Version 2 uses a Python module `build.py` to build. I noted this when trying to build version 1.9.8 and `./build.sh` failed: [Github Issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13871)